# Nested C++ templates

Tags: c++, thrust

I have a function called `add_vector_to_scalar` which adds a scalar value to a vector (`in`) and stores the result in another vector (`out`). I am learning C++ so I am not sure how to make the type parameter to `add_op generic`? I thought about adding another typename `T` but it did not work.

```
template<typename Vector>
void add(Vector& in, Vector& out, T& c) {
    transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), add_op<int>(c));   
}
```

The vector could be of two type:

```
device_vector<T>
host_vector<T>
```

The `add_op` struct looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct add_op : public thrust::unary_function<T,T> {
    const T c;  

    add_op(T v) : c(v) {}

    __host__ __device__
    T operator()(const T x) {
        return x + c;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the "adding another typename T" which did not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make `T` another template parameter of `add_vector_to_scalar`:

```
template<typename Vector, typename Scalar>
void add(const Vector& in, Vector& out, const Scalar& c) {
    transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), add_op<Scalar>(c));   
}
```

Note that I changed the `in` and `c` parameters to be taken as `const &` - as they're input-only parameters, you don't want to (be able to) modify them inside the function. And taking them as `const &` allows temporaries to be passed in, which is not possible with non-const references.