# Representing nested C++ templates

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

This is similar to the [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21427203/1782465) but it is concerning a templated vector component-wise addition function.

I have a function called `add` which takes two vectors and stores their addition in an output vector. I am learning c++ so I am not sure how to make the type parameter to `thrust::plus` generic? The problem is that `T` is the type parameter for both `device_vector` and `host_vector`; which should be a type parameter for `Vector`.

```
template<typename Vector, typename T>
void add(const Vector& in1, const Vector& in2, Vector& out) {
    transform(in1.begin(), in1.end(), in2.begin(), out.begin(), thrust::plus<T>(c));   
}
```

The vector could be of two type:

```
device_vector<T>
host_vector<T>
```

My code doesn't compile as it is complaining about:

```
error: no instance of function template "add" matches the argument list
```

How can I play the plus function generic so it easily works with `T` of either `device_vector<T>` or `host_vector<T>`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the container's `value_type`, and remove the second template parameter, as it cannot be deduced:

```
template<typename Vector>
void add(const Vector& in1, const Vector& in2, Vector& out) {
transform(in1.begin(), in1.end(), in2.begin(), out.begin(), 
          thrust::plus<typename Vector::value_type>(c)); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It works now so thank you. I come from Java so the generics system is a bit different to what I am used to.

Comment: @jimjampez C++ templates are completely different to Java generics, so you might as well "unlearn what you have learned", at least temporarily :)

Comment: LOL :) Do you have a book to recommend to learn C++ for a Java developer?

Comment: @jimjampez Not particularly for Java developers. Have a look at [this list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

Consult the docs of `thrust::host_vector` to see if it provides a nested typedef for its template parameters (such as `std::vector<T>` provides `std::vector<T>::value_type` identical to `T`). If it does, use it (as @juanchopanza's answer shows).

However, I tried looking at thrust docs briefly, and they didn't list such a typedef (unfortunate and surprising, but maybe true). If it indeed does not provide it, you have to use a template template parameter instead:

```
template<template <typename T, typename A> class Vector>
void add(const Vector<T, A>& in1, const Vector<T, A>& in2, Vector<T, A>& out) {
    transform(in1.begin(), in1.end(), in2.begin(), out.begin(), thrust::plus<T>(c));   
}
```

Note that you cannot just use `T` for the template template paremeter, you have to mirror the actual template parameters of the expected input class templates exactly. In C++11, you could help yourself a bit by using a variadic template:

```
template<template <typename T, typename... Other> class Vector>
void add(const Vector<T, Other...>& in1, const Vector<T, Other...>& in2, Vector<T, Other...>& out) {
    transform(in1.begin(), in1.end(), in2.begin(), out.begin(), thrust::plus<T>(c));   
}
```

Comment: I actually found the `value_type` definitions, see for example [here](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/host__vector_8h_source.html).

Comment: @juanchopanza That's good (and reasonable). Either Google took me to some irrelevant docs, or they provide the typedefs without documenting them.